# Register multiple Instances of a Spring Boot Eureka Client from a single host

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

**UPDATE**

The README in [this repo](https://github.com/mcwumbly/spring-boot-eureka-example) has been updated to demonstrate the solution in the accepted answer.

---

I'm working with a simple example of a Spring Boot Eureka service registration and discovery based on [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/).

If I start up one client instance, it registers properly, and it can see itself through the `DiscoveryClient`.  If I start up a second instance with a different name, it works as well.

But if I start up two instances with the same name, the dashboard only shows 1 instance running, and the `DiscoveryClient` only shows the second instance.

When I kill the 2nd instance, the 1st one is visible again through the dashboard and the discovery client.

Here are some more details about the steps I'm taking and what I'm seeing:

**Eureka Server**

Start the server

```
cd eureka-server
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Visit the Eureka dashboard at http://localhost:8761

Note that there are no 'Instances' yet registered

**Eureka Client**

Start up a client

```
cd eureka-client
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Visit the client directly at http://localhost:8080/

The `/whoami` endpoint will show the client's self-knowledge of its application name and port

```
{
  "springApplicationName":"eureka-client",
  "serverPort":"8080"
}
```

The `/instances` endpoint will take up to a minute to update, but should eventually show all the instances of `eureka-client` that have been registered with the Eureka Discovery Client.

```
[   
    {
      "host":"hostname",
      "port":8080,
      "serviceId":"EUREKA-CLIENT",
      "uri":"http://hostname:8080",
      "secure":false   
    } 
]
```

You can also visit the Eureka dashoboard again now and see it listed there.

**Spin up another client with a different name**

You can see that another client will be registred by doing the following:

```
cd eureka-client
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.application.name=foo -Dserver.port=8081
```

The `/whoami` endpoint will show the name `foo` and the port `8081`.

In a minute or so, the `/instances` endpoint will show the information about this `foo` instance too.

On the Eureka dashboard, two clients will now be registered.

**Spin up another client with the *same* name**

Now try spinning up another instance of `eureka-client` by only over-riding the port parameter:

```
cd eureka-client
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8082
```

The `/whoami` endpoint for `http://localhost:8082` shows what we expect.

In a minute or so, the `/instances` endpoint now shows the instance running on port 8082 also, but for some reason, it doesn't show the instance running on port 8080.

And if we check the `/instances` endpoint on `http://localhost:8080` we also now only see the instance running on 8082 (even though clearly, the one on 8080 is running since that's what we're asking for.

The Eureka dashboard only shows 1 instance of `eureka-client` running.

What's going on here?

Let's try killing the instance running on 8082 and see what happens.

When we query `/instances` on 8080, it still only shows the instance on 8082.

But a minute later, that goes away and we just see the instance on 8080 again.

The question is, why don't we see both instances of `eureka-client` when they are both running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For local deployments, try to **configure {namespace}.instanceId property in eureka-client.properties** (or eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId for proper yaml file in case of Spring Cloud based setup). It's deeply rooted in the way Eureka server calculates application lists and compares InstanceInfo for the PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl - when no more concrete data (e.g.: instance metadata is available) they try to get the id from the hostname..

I wouldn't recommend it for AWS deployment though, cause messing around with instanceId will bring you trouble figuring out which machine hosts a particular service - on the other hand I doubt that you'll hosts two identical services on one machine, right?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it before, but it looks like this is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653420/netflix-eureka-and-2-instances-of-application-on-local-environment

(Small typo in the property I needed to set, it should be `eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId`)

I started the second instance with `mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port8082 -Deureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=instance2` and it shows up in the dashboard and the response from the `DiscoveryClient` now.

Comment: I found `{namespace}.instanceId` to be working and not `eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId` with the eureka master branch as of today.

Comment: Maybe it got deprecated and finally removed - IMHO namespaces are more robust. I'll verify it in the underlying impl. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get all instances show up in the admin portal by setting unique euraka.instance.hostname in your Eureka configuration file.

The hostname is used as key for storing the InstanceInfo in com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application (since no UniqueIdentifier is set). So you have to use unique hostnames. When you test ribbon in this scenario you would see that the load won't be balanced.

Following application.yml is example:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:0}

info:
  component: example.server

logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'OFF'
    org.springframework.cloud: 'DEBUG'

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 1
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

It's a bug before in Eureka, you can check further information in https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/134