# Spring cloud registering multiple instances of same service

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am developing a microservice, using Spring Boot, that exposes REST Endpoint. Because of scalability, I have to run multiple instances of this services on a different port. What will be the configurations for the applications so that it can register with eureka and requests are load balanced? I am using Spring cloud config, Eureka server and zuul.

Comment: I think it should work with eureka if you run two instances of the eureka client what you need to do is run it on different ports. Eureka and Zuul are smart enough to load balance it. Also add some code that you have tried if it is not working. This question is too wide to answer. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253363/register-multiple-instances-of-a-spring-boot-eureka-client-from-a-single-host

Comment: but, what if we want to mask multiple ports from clients? meaning that we want to publish our service on a single port, And hide the load balancing procedure from clients. but in the back-end incoming requests are distributed among multiple instances on different ports. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attaching following entries in the client properties file will do the trick.  This is for Spring cloud config dalston

```
eureka.instance.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spri‌​ng.application.insta‌​nce_id:${random.valu‌​e}}
```

Comment: but, what if we want to mask multiple ports from clients? meaning that we want to publish our service on a single port, And hide the load balancing procedure from clients. but in the back-end incoming requests are distributed among multiple instances on different ports. how to achieve that?

Comment: A client will not interact with the service directly. A Client will interact via ZUUL or any gateway which will take care of load balancing and routing. ZUUL or API gateway will always run on a specific port and client will interact with the services using that specific port.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to register with `Eureka` instead of `Config` server.

To register multiple instances that might be running in the same host but listening on a different port you would need to set `eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId` to a unique value maybe using:

`eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${random.int}`

Comment: But after adding this it still shows only last registered instance in Eureka.

Comment: Found the solution eureka.instance.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}